# Fetching Data from DB using streams

Tags: java, stream

Recently, I was asked how to retrieve data from a database without using SQL queries. They suggested using streams to accomplish this, and I'd like someone to explain how this can be done.

I initially mentioned ORM frameworks, but the interviewer said that wasn't the right answer as the frameworks use sql queries against the database to retrieve data.

Comment: Are we missing some context? Because if you want to retrieve data from a database you need to write a query in whatever syntax the db supports, period.

Comment: The question as posed to you (_"retrieve data from a database without using SQL queries"_) is lacking sufficient context to be answered.  They obviously are looking for a very specific answer that will depend on the details of their environment.  If this caused you to fail an interview, I'd say your were lucky to find out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the answer they were looking for is [log-based Change Data Capture (CDC)](https://debezium.io/blog/2018/07/19/advantages-of-log-based-change-data-capture/), either via established tools like Debezium or custom-built CDC connectors. The gist of this approach is to read directly from the write-ahead log as CRUD operations happen in the database, rather than poll the database on some cadence using SQL (aka query-based CDC).